# Get the value of input text with document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some code, where i want to get the value of an input text introduced by the user

**Get the value**

```
       var inputTextValue = document.getElementsByClassName("something");        
       alert("inputTextValue.value);
```

**Creation of the input text**

```
 function createHour(){
    var hour = document.createElement("INPUT");
    hour.id = "something";
    defineButtonHour(hour);
    //after: -code to append to div
  }

function defineHour(hour) {
  hour.className = "something";
}
```

The alert just print undefined.

Comment: Try change `alert("inputTextValue.value);` to `alert(inputTextValue.value);`

Comment: Are `defineButtonHour` and `defineHour` meant to be the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getElementsByClassName returns an array with all the elements that match the class, you need to iterate over the array, or access the one that you want by providing an index"

```
alert(inputTextValue[0].value);
```

also theres an extra semicolon in your alert that shouldnt be there

Comment: The extra semicolon was a mistake on the copy-paste. But your solution worked, you have my up vote and the accept of the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputTextValue = document.getElementsByClassName("something");
```

Returns a nodelist of all the nodes with the class something.   A nodelist is kind of an array.  you can write:

```
var inputTextValue = document.getElementsByClassName("something")[0];
```

If you can guarantee there will be at least one and you only want one.

Also, your alert has a quote where it doesn't need one:

```
alert(inputTextValue.value);
```